# How to search for previous commands in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command

How can i get my terminal history in date wise. I forgot few of the important commands which i ave typed last night but i want those commands. So please help me out how can i get the history date wise.

I typed history in the terminal but it is not been showing the dates, so i am also confused where i will get those commands, so please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal, do the following:

*Note: I have done the ff on Mac. In `Ubuntu`, you can use `bashrc` instead of `bash_profile`.*

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

> If the HISTTIMEFORMAT is set, the time stamp information associated
>   with each history entry is written to the history file, marked with
>   the history comment character.

then, execute:

```
history
```

you can now see your command history like this:

```
398  05/09/13 08:45:15 ifconfig
399  05/09/13 08:45:15 ./adb kill-server
400  05/09/13 08:45:15 ./adb start-server
401  05/09/13 08:45:15 ./adb devices
```